# Inserting data into HTML via Objective-C

Tags: html, objective-c, email, hyperlink

I want to add a hot html link to an email in objective-c. I know that the way it would typically work if I had a specific url would be something along the lines of:

```
[composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example text, 
<a href=\"google.com\">Link Name</a> More example text"];
```

But I want to have a hot link with a custom generated url as both the title of the link and the website of the link, so something more like:

```
[composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example text, 
<a href=%@>%@</a>", self.link, self.link];
```

But this is crashing on me. Ideas?

Comment: Apart from the missing `]`, the value for href should enclosed with quotes like `href=\"%@\"`. You can also use `href='%@'`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close this statement:

```
[composer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example text, 
<a href=%@>%@</a>", self.link, self.link];
```

Needs another close square bracket at the end.

Plus you should have wrapped the href value in quotes, escaped of course.

```
\" value \"
```